WKT Point Geometry to Coordinates (latitude and longitude)
I am working on a Tableau project that provides an analysis of congestion in NYC. I have a data set that shows the daily volume of cars, the borough, the origin street (fromst), destination street (tost), and a WKT Geometry point with the location of the street. I am attempting to convert this WKT Point to a latitude and longitude coordinate so that I can create an interactive map comparing the car volumes of different sections of Manhattan.
Example:



WKT Geom




POINT (993228.5264971782 150600.75237618468)


POINT (1026062.2270505144 269645.6241261366)



The data set can be found here on the NYC transportation site:
https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Transportation/Automated-Traffic-Volume-Counts/7ym2-wayt/data_preview
I am new to this WKT format and been looking everywhere to find a conversion but haven't had any luck finding the spatial reference the data description is referring to.

@zabop Instead of passive aggressively sending a link on how to ask a question, maybe try to make actual suggestions so that I can clarify or add whatever is necessary to answer the question? :) Thanks!

I think @zabop is trying to ask you what have you tried so far, list the links that were dead ends, explain the processes you have tried, expand upon your expected output and  take more time to be specific in what you are asking. I know a lot of coordinate mapping is more or less private or internally referenced you may need to grab additional data sources and combine them to make your own mapping.

Try the following
In Tableau Desktop, right click on your WKT Geom field in the data pane (left margin) and then change the datatype from String to Spatial. If the WKT is well-structured, Tableau will convert your values to a spatial type that you can work with. I'm not sure which EPSG code it uses in this case, but go with the default for the moment.
Once you have a spatial field, if you place that field on the details shelf, then Tableau populates the pre-defined fields Latitude(Generated) and Longitude(Generated). Put those fields on Rows and Columns respectively. You should now see the whole spatial structure as one mark.
If you want individual parts of your geometric structure to be selectable, put other dimensions into play, say if you have a field called Province or Facility you can put those fields on Color or Detail shelves to distinguish the individual provinces or facilities. You can also use your spatial field when calling spatial functions like Area(), Outline() etc.
If the automatic default conversion from WKT is not lining up as you like, you could pre-process with Python or QGIS or something to create a GeoJSON or shape file instead.
It would be nice if Tableau had an explicit function to convert WKT to spatial that would take a spatial reference system as an argument. They probably would already if Sarah Battersby were still there :-(

Hi Alex, thanks for your answer, however I do not see the option to change the datatype to spatial available. Would I need to upload this file in a different type to work? I currently have this uploaded as a CSV.

To change a datatype for a field listed in the data pane on the left margin, you can either click on the data type icon to the left of the field name, say ABC for string or # for number or a calendar for a date, and choose the new data type. Or you can right click on the field name and choose Change Data Type

P.S. If you are using an old version of Tableau, then the automatic conversion of String WKT to spatial may not be available, but it is available in recent versions - I think since early 2023

So im using the most recent version of Tableau Desktop and still cannot find the option for spatial. I did reach out to the data provider to see if they have a spatial reference or even their own conversion but do you believe converting to GeoJSON like you said is my best bet for now?

Can you see how to change the data type of a field? Here is a description of how to change the data type of a field from a string to a date https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/data_dateparse.htm The procedure to change the data type from string to spatial is identical. Do you see Date as an option but don't see Spatial? Or do you just not see the change data type option at all?

I was able to change the data type to spatial via the data source tab (I was previously trying to change it on the worksheet). However when I add the field to the sheet it now shows as an empty map.

See the answer. Once you have a spatial field on the detail shelf, then double click on Latitude(Generated) and Longitude(Generated) or explicitly add them to Rows and Columns respectively. Then add other fields to get color

I believe the issue is that when i add this field to the details shelf it defaults to a calculation using COLLECT for spatial fields, which results in null values for latitude and longitude when those are in the rows and columns

The COLLECT() is correct. Take a look at the coordinates in your WKT strings. Those are not latitudes and longitudes. Find out what spatial reference system the data is using
